# Uploaded images deleted on save in Drupal

Tags: entities

A certain *content-type* in my installation does not save images in it's gallery anymore.

The image is being uploaded, registered in *file_managed* with status 0, and stored in sites/default/files.

On save the status does not get updated to 1 in the database, therefore the file gets deleted.

I entered some debug code, and it turns out that **file_field_presave()** never even gets called for the uploaded file.

Curiously on my testing copy of the same system it works, the function gets called and the status is updated to 1 in the database.

I compared the *content-type* and *field-type* settings, and they are the same.

I also compared all drupal-files again (diff -r), except for database configuration ant .htaccess they are the same.

update.php doesn't do any update, and the modules have no security updates pending.

How could I debug the problem? I don't know how to look deeper. Is it possible that the database is somehow inconsintent?

Thanks a bunch for your help people.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a permissions issue since it involves putting new files in the filesystem and it's different on two otherwise similar systems.

Comment: thanks for the tip. permissions in the file system? I checked that, the uploaded files are already stored in sites/default/files until one clicks save.

Comment: @betherwisser are there issues if Drupal only has group ownership on the files?

Comment: I don't know. If you've checked that the files are being saved in the filesystem, that seems like it's not likely to be the problem.

Comment: what permissions are on the files? Who owns the files? Is any of that different from the rest of your install?

Comment: @Andy How is this content-type's image field configuration different to another content-type's that work. Are you using the Media module widget at all, and if so what are your enabled URI schemes?

Comment: Surely you already checked it, but could it be a problem with the extension? Perhaps if you allow for "txt" files (lowcase) and you are uploading "TXT", it may work perfectly on Windows systems but fail in Linux. Just an idea.

Comment: Why don't you run a diff on the SQL dump from each database. This will help identify any inconsistencies in the database configuration that you were looking for.

Comment: because it's a testing vs a live system, 10 months of content are missing in the testing system /:

Comment: thanks for your comments.
The files are accepted and uploaded at first, so I'd exclude wrong file extensions.
Files are owned by a local user (SSH) and group www-data. Accordingly the rights are rwXrwXr--

Comment: So, I created the very same file permissions on the testing system – still works.
The testing system is using a copy of the live database now – and the problem is also on the testing system now. So I guess I need to do a diff on settings tables, at least.

Comment: Could you give a hint on which tables to check in particular? I saw some differences in `field_config_instance` which sounds promising, but deleting the differences didn't change anything.

Comment: I would look at the file_managed and file_usage tables. And here's another thing to try. Dump the SQL before and after a file upload on both sites (live and dev). Run the diff on each site's resulting SQL to what changed in dev, and what changed in live.

Comment: @J.Reynolds the only difference is that it's inside a field_collection. Another image in the same content-type works well. Widget type for both is `Image`.

Comment: Well difference is that when uploading the Image, in `file_managed` on testing status=1, on live status=0. Accordingly, in `file_usage` after Save there is an entry on testing, but not on live, where also the entry in `file_managed` gets deleted. That is the expected behaviour when `file_field_presave()` doesn't get called. Question is why it doesn't. /:

Comment: So I found differences in the table _field_config_instance_ for a configuration of this field collection. I copied the _data_ field from the testing database to the live database. Now I can upload images for newly created entries in the gallery. (:

Comment: @Andy `So I found differences in the table field_config_instance ` - can you shed some more light on this ? I have the same problem, in a field_collection, but I have it both on testing and on live.

Comment: Test if your files are getting deleted if, when editing the node, you also create a new revision. I had this problem consistently in quite a similar setup (and still do, and haven't solved it). But checking 'new revision' seems to help. And might be a clue.